# Find a set of numbers inside in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

```js
function BigNumebr(e) {
    let num = ["19", "25" , "30" , "13", "22"]
    if ()
}
```

I want to get the biggest number, middle number and small number use an array without any method, :)

Comment: there are strings, not numbers : none of them could be a biggest number, small number or whatever number... ;)

Comment: Could you please share the code you have tried?

Comment: >>I want to get the biggest number, middle number and small number use an array without any method, :)


What stopping you to give a try ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-on-demand service, where work orders are given and people code for you. Someone may very well answer this question before it gets closed, but it reduces the site's usefulness for everyone when they do.

Comment: @AbdoAdel is middle number meaning the position in the array (and if yes, what if the array contains an even number of elements), or the element closest to the average of all elements, or the elements closest to  the average of the min and max element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `sort()` to sort the array,
then pick the first, middle and last element from the sorted array.

```js
let num = ["19", "25" , "30" , "13", "22"];

const sorted = num.sort((a, b) => a - b);
const result = [sorted[0], sorted[Math.round((sorted.length - 1) / 2)], sorted[sorted.length-1]];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @MisterJojo the sorted array is `["13", "19", "22", "25", "30"]` so 22 is the middle element.

Answer (score -1):

Use Array.sort and then pick first, middle, last numbers.

Comment: Note that `sort()` will sort by string representations, even if the array contains integers.  Use `[].sort( (a,b)=> a < b ? -1 : a === b ? 0 : 1 )` to sort by numeric value comparison.